# pygame.error: video system not initialized. pygame.init() already called but without sys.exit()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pygame

Before you close this question this is not like other questions!

my question is how to fix `pygame.error: video system not initialized`and `pygame.init()` is already called but without `sys.exit()`?
because I have another tkinter window and I want to **exit the pygame window only**.

I know this is beginner question but I beginner at pygame and I don't know how to close pygame window without close the whole code. Help

code (with pygame.Error):

```py
class editor:
    def __init__(self):
        new_frm.pack_forget()
        welc.pack_forget()
        new_btn.pack_forget()

        ## FRAMES ##
        self.rot = Frame(root,width=root.winfo_screenwidth(),height=80,bg="#282828")
        self.rot.pack()

        # __|ADD A LAYOUT FOR ROOT|__ #
           # Resolution #
        # X #
        Label(self.rot,text=" X : ",bg="#282828",fg="white",borderwidth=0,font=("arial",17)).place(x=8,y=20)
        self.ent_x = Entry(self.rot,borderwidth=0,bg="#323232",width=5,fg="orange",font=("arial",20))
        self.ent_x.place(x=50,y=20,height=30)
        self.ent_x.insert(END,"600")
        # Y #
        Label(self.rot,text=" Y : ",bg="#282828",fg="white",borderwidth=0,font=("arial",17)).place(x=147,y=20)
        self.ent_y = Entry(self.rot,borderwidth=0,bg="#323232",width=5,fg="orange",font=("arial",20))
        self.ent_y.place(x=200,y=20,height=30)
        self.ent_y.insert(END,"400")
        # RUN #
        run_load = Image.open(os.path.join(dirname, 'Data/Icons/RUN.png'))
        width, height = run_load.size
        run_load = run_load.resize((int(width/16),int(height/16)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        run_render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(run_load)
        self.run_btn = Button(self.rot,image=run_render,bg="#282828",borderwidth=0,activebackground="orange",command=lambda: self.run(int(self.ent_x.get()),int(self.ent_y.get())))
        self.run_btn.place(relx=1,x=-60,y=20)
        # To Fix if "run" image not loading #
        canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master)
        canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
    
    def run(self, x: int, y: int):
        pygame.init()
        size = width, height = x, y
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                   # Here is the Error :
                    pygame.quit()
```

so the Error at the func `run` in the bottom when I try to quit `pygame` by use `pygame.quit()` and I will have `pygame.error`.I was trying to use `pygame.display.quit()` and the same Error ;)

Thx for reading [RIP English]

If you know how to **quit the pygame window only** please tell me as answer.

EDIT:
if I try to do this:

```py
        while 1:
            pygame.init()
            ev = pygame.event.poll() 
            if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.display.quit()
```

it's will be close without error but the tkinter window will be crashed ;)

EDIT 2:
if I try to do this:

```py
        while 1:
            try:
                if pygame.event.poll().type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.display.quit()
            except:
                pygame.init()
                if pygame.event.poll().type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.display.quit()
```

it's will be close without error but the tkinter window will be crashed ;)

Comment: Please Help if you know the answer please tell me.

Comment: `pygame.init()` only needs to be called once, yet you have it in a `while 1` loop. That's what the error is telling you . You should modify your program so that line cna only run one time.

Comment: @Random Davis thx I found the solution and I posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

to fix this i want to finish the while loop after closing while `pygame.init()` is running in the while loop. it's fix that crash by finishing the loop:

```py
g = True
while g:
    pygame.init()
    if pygame.event.poll().type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.display.quit()
        g = False
```

so the solution steps are:

1. add `pygame.init()` to the while loop
2. finish the while loop after close it by add boolean var to fix crashing in the step one.
3. and that's it.

thx for reading.